# plpgsql: How can we give "max" value to varchar data type?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

For example:
Suppose i want to use a string which should be maximum in numbers, so can i use "varchar(max)" in my query? 
Here "max" is not an aggregate function. It's a maximum number of characters.

Example:

```
declare
       name varchar(20);
       details varchar(max); --Its not working in plpgsql.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply leave out any restriction:

```
declare
   name varchar(20);
   details varchar;
```

More details in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html